# FLTK libs seen as wrong architecture in XCode

Tags: macos, xcode6, fltk

I'm trying to revive an old project that uses FLTK.  At link time, this happens:

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/ken/Programs/comp236/fltk-1.1.7/lib/libfltk_gl.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/ken/Programs/comp236/fltk-1.1.7/lib/libfltk_gl.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/ken/Programs/comp236/fltk-1.1.7/lib/libfltk.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/ken/Programs/comp236/fltk-1.1.7/lib/libfltk.a

IT DOES NOT MATTER whether I build my project for i386 or x86_64, same message.  Do I need to do something to the FLTK makefile to build its libraries differently?

XCode 6.2 on MacOS 10.9.5

Comment: To check the slices contained, use the `file` command in teminal: `file /Users/ken/Programs/comp236/fltk-1.1.7/lib/libfltk_gl.a`. Post the results.

Comment: Please, what exactly do you mean by "slices"?  I followed your idea and it wasn't very informative (and sorry I can't get this silly thing to preserve my newlines!):     

`$ file libfltk*.a     
libfltk.a:        current ar archive random library

libfltk_forms.a:  current ar archive random library

libfltk_gl.a:     current ar archive random library

libfltk_images.a: current ar archive random library

libfltk_jpeg.a:   current ar archive random library

libfltk_png.a:    current ar archive random library`